# Snakemake: sub-workflow error when executing in LSF cluster

Tags: lsf, snakemake

I have two Snakemake workflows that are very similar. Both of them share a sub-workflow and a couple of includes. Both of them work when doing dry runs. Both of them use the same cluser config file, and I'm running them with the same launch command. One of them fails when submitting to the LSF cluster with this error:

```
Executing subworkflow wf_common.
WorkflowError:
Config file __default__ not found.
```

I'm wondering whether it's "legal" in Snakemake for two workflows to share a sub-workflow, like in this case, and if not, whether the fact that I ran the workflow that does work first could have this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try Snakemake 3.12.0? It fixed a bug with passing the cluster config to a subworkflow. I would think that this solves your problem.

Comment: Hm, it did work initially after the upgrade, but now I'm seeing the same error for both workflows.